# How to test if a statistic is different from zero using bootstrapping

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap

I have a sample of 300 people with their credit scores recorded at different points in time (a year ago and their current scores).

I defined my statistic as follows:

$\phi = \frac{q_{90}^2}{q_{10}^2} - \frac{q_{90}^1}{q_{10}^1}$

Where $q_x^t$ is the $x$th percentile of the sample in period $t$.

Naturally, I have no idea what distribution this statistic would follow, so I plotted its empirical distribution with bootstrapping (1K repetitions). The histogram looks as follows:
[image: empirical distribution]

The mean of the empirical distribution is -0.006 and its empirical variance is 0.002.

I now want to carry out the following hypothesis test:

$H_0$: $\phi = 0$

$H_1$: $\phi \neq 0$

**My question:** Assuming that $\phi$ follows a normal distribution, how should I build a significance test to test this hypothesis?

I want to test this using $z = \frac{\phi_{obs} - \space 0}{\sqrt{0.002}}$, but I don't know what value to use for $\phi_{obs}$. Should I use all 300 entries in my data? Should I pick one of the $\phi$s from the bootstrap? Should I use the mean of all the bootstrapped $\phi$s?

Comment: I vote for the mean of bootstrapped $\phi$ s (=-0.006) among the choices.  Perhaps more rigorous would be: derive the limiting distribution for $q_{10}^{1}, q_{90}^{1}, q_{10}^{2}, q_{90}^{2}$ separately, then construct the distribution for $\phi$ using the delta method.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you would use the mean of the bootstrapped $\phi$ please?

Comment: I don't see the point of assuming normality or of dividing by the bootstrap s.e. Why not just find the bootstrap confidence interval and see if it contains zero? Also, I hope you are resampling the vectors intact to preserve the correlation, which is a hugely important aspect here.

Comment: How do you find the bootstrap confidence interval? It is my understanding that bootstrapping is used to estimate the mean and variance of a distribution, which is later helpful for building a statistic. I do not know how to build a CI on the bootstrap directly.